# Harsh corner on a shape drawn with rounded corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create a custom shape surrounding some nodes. I have used a `\path` to draw the shape but I don't get a `rounded corner` where I begin drawing the shape. Here's my MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path [rounded corners=10pt, draw] (0,0) -- 
      ++(50em, 0) --
      ++(0em,-20.5em) -- ++(-24em, 0em) -- 
      ++(0, 11.25em) -- ++(-26em, 0) --
      (0,0)
      {}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

How do I get rid of the harsh corner at top-left?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The start and end points are not connected, therefore the `rounded corners` is not applied to them. They can be connected by `cycle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path [rounded corners=10pt, draw] (0,0) --
      ++(50em, 0) --
      ++(0em,-20.5em) -- ++(-24em, 0em) --
      ++(0, 11.25em) -- ++(-26em, 0) --
      cycle
      {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]